# Flutter Project Package Error (in ios, lib etc...)

Tags: flutter, dart, package

[image]

I don't know why there are errors in packages.
It seems to be a problem after git clone, but it cannot be stopped because it is uncertain.
If you create a new flutter project, the packages and folders such as ios and lib will not be created together...
If you know how to solve this problem, please answer please.

Comment: Try running `flutter pub get` at your project directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first do project clean and then pub get to get dependencies like below.
run this commands in your terminal.

```
 flutter clean
 flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in terminal:

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: I've already done this, but the red color disappeared and came back

Answer (score 0):

try using the below commands:

```
 flutter clean 
 flutter pub get
```

Comment: There is nothing new you have added - this is a duplicate of earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps one by one:

Open the terminal inside your flutter project folder and then perform,

```
flutter clean    
flutter pub get    
cd ios
pod repo update
pod install
```

Re-run your project.

Answer (score 0):

I entered all directories with pubspec.yaml file and ran flutter clean->flutter pub get to resolve it. Thank you.